# Columnas de las tablas no se adaptan a div en bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, table

Tengo el sgte código que al visualizar en mi tabla la cabecera que contiene los nombre de cada columna se sale del div.

```
  <div class="col-sm col-lg">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <nav>
                                            <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                                                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-fee" role="tab" aria-selected="true">PRESUPUESTO</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </nav>
                                        <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-fee" role="tabpanel">
                                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                                    <thead class="text-center">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_NOM_PAC)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_NOM_ODON)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_RUT)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_POR)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_SUB)
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                OPCIONES
                                                            </th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                      </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-interests" role="tabpanel">


                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Que clase me falta o no estoy aplicando correctamente dentro del div o por defecto dentro del table?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisando y probando encontré la solución añadí un fila previamente `<div class="row text-center">`  y posteriormente en mi segundo div añadí la clase `table-responsive`

```
<div class="col-sm col-lg">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <nav>
                                            <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
                                                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-fee" role="tab" aria-selected="true">PRESUPUESTO</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </nav>
                                        <div class="row text-center"> 
                                            <div class="tab-content table-responsive" id="nav-tabContent">
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-fee" role="tabpanel">
                                                    <table class="table table-striped">
                                                        <thead class="text-center">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_COD)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_NOM_PAC)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_NOM_ODON)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_RUT)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_DEN_PAC)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_PIE_DEN)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_TRA_PAC)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_PRE)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_POR)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MODEL_PRESUPUESTO.PRE_VAL_SUB)
                                                                </th>
                                                                <th>
                                                                    OPCIONES
                                                                </th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-interests" role="tabpanel">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Y quedaría de la sgte manera que es lo que en un principio necesitaba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]